# Wait for POST to finish, then switch to PUT

Tags: angular, rxjs

I'm struggling in finding a solution to my problem:
I'm working on a "survey" module where you answer some questions. But the problem lies in the "answer" compontent.
Lets say you have an input field that POSTs your answer on every input, and after the first time you posted it needs to PUT based on the id the POST returns.

**What i have so far:** (this is just an example, so something might not be correct, but the problem is still the same)

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-answer',
    template: '<input [(ngModel)]="answer.text" (ngModelChange)="change()">',
})
export class AnswerNgmodelComponent {
    answer: Answer = { id: 0, text: '' };
    private answerChanged = new Subject<string>();

    constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
        this.answerChanged
            .pipe(
                debounceTime(1000),
                switchMap((res) =>
                    this.answer.id > 0
                        ? this.updateAnswer(this.answer)
                        : this.postAnswer(this.answer)
                )
            )
            .subscribe((res) => {
                if(res) {
                    this.answer.id = res;
                }
            });
    }

    change() {
        this.answerChanged.next();
    }

    //Returns id of created answer
    postAnswer(answer: Answer): Observable<number> {
        return this.http.post<number>('http://api.com/answer', answer);
    }

    //Updates answer
    updateAnswer(answer: Answer): Observable<any> {
        return this.http.put('http://api.com/answer/' + answer.id, answer);
    }
}

export class Answer {
    id: number;
    text: string;
}
```

**The problem i'm running into:**
The first time you answer the question we need to wait for the post to finish and set the id of the answer. But if theres abit of delay in the post request theres a window where you can "update" your answer when it hasnt finished posting yet, and is going to post the answer  again.

How can i wait for the "create" post to finish, and then begin to "update" after?

**UPDATE**
Apparently it is as easy as changing switchMap to concatMap - thanks to @akotech

Comment: use `concatMap` instead of `switchMap`

Comment: @akotech if i for example run this code to test it:  
    test() {
        this.answer.text = 'post1';
        this.change();
        setTimeout(() => { this.answer.text = 'post2'; this.change(); }, 1200);
        setTimeout(() => { this.answer.text = 'post3'; this.change(); }, 2400);
        setTimeout(() => { this.answer.text = 'post4'; this.change(); }, 3600);
    }
And lets say both the post and put answer has a delay of 5000ms. The answer gets created once (perfect!), but gets updated with 'post4' 3 times in a row. is there any way to make it only update once? Sorry for formatting

Comment: You're getting 3x 'post4' because you're using `this.answer` as the argument of the update method call. So the 'post2', 'post3' and 'post4' update calls end up pointing at the same object and therefore at the time of execution all three point to the last value of that object.  If you can ignore intermediate update requests, you could go back to `switchMap` and add a 2nd `debounce` to debounce the notifications while the post request is ongoing [Example here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-yic3s7). If you want to process all request, use the answer text for the calls.

Answer (score 0):

You can save the request subscription and unsubscribe before the new request if exists, This will cancel active request.

```js
@Component({
    selector: 'app-answer',
    template: '<input [(ngModel)]="answer.text" (ngModelChange)="change()">',
})
export class AnswerNgmodelComponent {
    answer: Answer = { id: 0, text: '' };
    private answerChanged = new Subject<string>();
    private activeRequestSubscription: Subscription = null;

    constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
        this.answerChanged
            .pipe(
                debounceTime(1000),
                switchMap((res) =>
                    this.answer.id > 0
                        ? this.updateAnswer(this.answer)
                        : this.postAnswer(this.answer)
                )
            )
            .subscribe((res) => {
                if(res) {
                    this.answer.id = res;
                }
            });
    }

    change() {
        this.answerChanged.next();
    }

    //Returns id of created answer
    postAnswer(answer: Answer): Observable<number> {
        this.activeRequestSubscription?.unsubscribe();
        this.activeRequestSubscription = this.http.post<number>('http://api.com/answer', answer);
        return this.activeRequestSubscription;
    }

    //Updates answer
    updateAnswer(answer: Answer): Observable<any> {
        this.activeRequestSubscription?.unsubscribe();
        this.activeRequestSubscription = this.http.put('http://api.com/answer/' + answer.id, answer);
        return this.activeRequestSubscription;
    }
}

export class Answer {
    id: number;
    text: string;
}
```

I recomends to you to use a service for manage http requests.

Answer (score -1):

Use post request only and maintain id
when you first time hit post request you passed id: 0
after that you will have a id for update
then you can pass id in post data
so in simple words if you have id=0 it means you answer first time in particular survey.
and if you have any id from your backend,  you pass that id in your data and update existing pool

example:

1. when you first time answer:
   your req data:

   ```
   let reqData = {
      id: 0,
      content: 'test',
      des: 'test'
   }
   ```
2. when you update your answer  pool:
   your req data:

   ```
   let reqData = {
     id: 112,   
     content: 'test',
     des: 'test'
    }
   ```

note: id 112  generated by your backend